# how to make variable take numeric value?

Tags: javascript

if possible,
how to make nam store integer 100?

In javascript,

```
    var ClubsK = 100;
var str = "file:///C:/Users/Lopchan/Desktop/black%20jack/images/ClubsK.png";
var nam = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1, str.lastIndexOf("."));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ClubsK; //gives 100
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nam; //gives ClubsK
```

Comment: Other than the obvious `nam = 100`, it's not really clear what you're asking or after here.

Comment: Eval, new Function.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to do is accessing a dynamic variable in this case I recommend to use an object instead.

```
var data = {
  ClubsK: 100
};

var str = "file:///C:/Users/Lopchan/Desktop/black%20jack/images/ClubsK.png";
var nam = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1, str.lastIndexOf("."));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data['ClubsK']; //gives 100
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[nam]; //gives 100
```